# Create new user for one account in Snowflake organization

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, admin

I am orgadmin for my organization and wanted to create new user for one of the snowflake account. In primary URL i can create new user and role but how can be created for another account under organization umbrella?

Comment: Orgadmin is for managing and creating new accounts. For creating new user one must connect to that account. Following are the actions Orgadmin can do: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/organizations.html#orgadmin-role

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the URL for the account you want to create the user.
2. Once you log in, you have to create the user in that account.

Comment: 1. URL is available
2. this is the issue here, who can login to the account URL ? and how to find

Comment: You would have had to define the initial admin user and password when you created the account: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-account.html